# Add custom taxonomy to default category taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm trying to add a custom taxonomy to default category taxonomy but I could not figure out how to.

I tried this but failed :/

```
register_taxonomy(
    'oyuncu',
    'category',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'label' => __('Oyuncular', 'series'),
        'query_var' => 'oyuncu',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'oyuncular'),
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'supports' => array('thumbnail'),
    )
);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can't assign a taxonomy to a taxonomy. You may only assign it to a post type. But you could use metadata (custom fields) to relate two different taxonomies.

Comment: @SallyCJ I'm trying to struct cast ( actors ) to category ( tv-serie )

Comment: What is `actors`? A post type? And is `tv-serie` a *term* in the standard `category` taxonomy? Or is `tv-serie` a custom taxonomy?

Comment: @SallyCJ actors are taxonomy with hierarchical => false. tv-serie is the standard category not custom one.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't understand why you're doing that. Why not just assign the `actors` taxonomy to the relevant post type - e.g. for the standard `post` post type: `register_taxonomy( 'actors', 'post', array( ... ) )` ? That way, when creating/editing a post, you can choose a standard category and a `actors` term for that post.

Comment: @SallyCJ my posts are episode of tv-series. categories are tv-series. seasons are sub-categories of tv-series. I just want to assing actors to seasons or tv-series. Because there is a lot of episodes to add actors and I have to show actors in my tv-series(category) page.

Comment: It'd be easy to query the "actors" if you make an "actor" a sub-category of a "season" or "tv serie". But if that's not an option for you, then you can try my earlier suggestion - use custom field. E.g. You can add a [ACF taxonomy field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/) on the "seasons" and "tv series" category edit page, then you would use meta query when querying for the "actors" for a "season" or "tv serie".

Comment: @SallyCJ that makes sense, I will try that. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help and please ignore my previous comment (that I've deleted). And if you want, you could write an answer and share your solution. It could save someone's time in the future :)