# Attach a post type to other one

Tags: custom-post-types

I have 2 custom post types, I want to add a select input in one of custom post type (when I add or edit a post) to select the other custom post type.

I looked at this function : `add_meta_box`, but I am not sure it's the correct way to do it ? Can I use more simple thing from Wordpress ?

Comment: Your question sounds similar to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/359539), except that's for a taxonomy. Why are you attaching the post type, perhaps there's another way to achieve your goals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Many to Many Relationship between Two Custom Post Types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51386/many-to-many-relationship-between-two-custom-post-types)